# How to redirect to a particular section of a page using HTML or jQuery?

Tags: html

i have a menu bar that has 3 anchor elements and i want to load the content of those elements while staying on the same page.
i want to do so without making linking to another html file that has those contents.
i have tried adding id's to the divs and linking to them with an anchor element but that doesnt make the other content disappear no matter what link i am on

```
<div class = "logo">
        <a href="dspr.html"><img src="logo-removebg-preview.png"></a>
        </div>
        <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="dspr.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="programs.html">Programs</a></li>
            <li><a href="library.html">Library</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">عربي</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<main>

<section class = "inner-section">

    <div class="sub-menu">
        <ul>
            <a href="#who-wrapper"><li>Who We Are</li></a>
            <a href="#who-wrapper"><li>Our Values</li></a>
            <a href=""><li>History & Structure</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div  class="wrapper">
        <div id ="who-wrapper"class="who-body">
            <h3>Who We Are?</h3>
```

[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWT69.png)

Comment: What exactly do you want? Could you give some more context to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use anchor tag to call the specific section

```
<a href="#id_of_section">Anchor content</a>
<section id="id_of_section">
    some content here
</section>
```